# How can I give my raw HTML data to Component Decorator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

pass data directly to the decorator like this

```
  @Component({
      template: template
    })
```

where template is raw html.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass html data as a string

```
@Component({
      template: {{htmlData}}    //interpolation
})
```

So for var

```
class SomeComponent {
htmlData:any;

 getData() {
   this.htmlData = `<div>Test Div</div>`
 }
}
```

Comment: actually i need it as var, its raw html data from db.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: this not work cause htmlData var wont get in the component decoraor